# is there any actionscript bytecode debugger?

Tags: actionscript, bytecode

is there any known tool for debugging action script bytecode
just like debugging x86 binary code with IDA or olly debugger??

I have no source code. and I want to debug the ABC bytecode line by line.
SWFWire does not support this, neither FireBug.

I want to debug such ActionScript bytecode.

```
    push "a"
    96 03 00 00 01 00
    getVariable 
    1C
    push 248
    96 05 00 07 F8 00 00 00
    equals 
    0E
    not 
    12
    if true goto #159
    9D 02 00 1D 00
    push "a"
    96 03 00 00 01 00
    push "a"
    96 03 00 00 01 00
    getVariable 
    1C
    push 476
    96 05 00 07 DC 01 00 00
    add 
    0A
    setVariable 
    1D
    getVariable 
    1C
    jump #20
    99 02 00 E0 FD
```

I want to set a breakpoint somewhere I want and follow the execution path
line by line.

I've googled for a while and there is no software which supports this.
thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm searching for the same thing...